# Time format of text box in excel user form

Tags: excel, time-format

I have below code to set time format of atext box "txtA" in userform.

```
Private Sub txtA_Afterupdate()
Dim tString As String
 With txtA

'Check if user put in a colon or not
 If InStr(1, .Value, ":", vbTextCompare) = 0 And Len(.Value) > 1 Then

'If not, make string 4 digits and insert colon
 tString = Format(.Value, "0000")
 tString = Left(tString, 2) & ":" & Right(tString, 2)
 txtA.Value = Format(TimeValue(tString), "hh:mm")
Else

'Otherwise, take value as given
 .Value = Format(.Value, "hh:mm")
End If
End With
```

Assume I have say 20 text boxes,(A - E) make one group (F- H)make another group and so on. now I have 2 Q.
1-Should i apply above code to each textbox individually or there's a code that i just can put all text boxes name of userform in it?
2- with input data higher than 23:59 it gives error i changed the format to [h]:mm but didn't work,I want if user enters 35:45 the time be shown as it is not like d:hh:mm

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question 1 is that you need to apply the code to every textbox but first you should take the code that you have and make it a function that you can call from each txt$_Afterupdate() sub.

The function will need to know which textbox to format so it will have to receive the textbox object

```
function formatTime(objTXT As Object)
```

then in the code replace txtA with objTXT

```
objTXT.Value = Format(TimeValue(tString), "hh:mm")
```

then you will call formatTime from each textbox Afterupdate and pass the textbox object.

```
Private Sub txtA_Afterupdate()

    formatTime me.txtA

end sub
```

I need to think about your second question but I'm pretty sure that you can't use the format hh:mm if you want to accept more than 24 hours.